# Semantics of a class within a struct

Tags: swift, data-structures, linked-list, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm reviewing data structures and came across something that I never realized when it comes to Linked Lists.  This specific example is for Linked Lists, but the concept I think will be largely around properties that follow reference semantics within a struct (value semantics).

Here is the situation: I declare a new node, and say that this new node and `head` in the LinkedList share the same reference.  Then, I change the value of `head`.  I would assume that since the new node and `head` reference the same space in memory, they would both reflect the update.  However, this is not the case.  `head` shows the update` but the new node does not.  Please see code below.

```
public struct LinkedList<Value> {
    public var head: Node<Value>?

    public init() {}
    /* 
    append, push, isEmpty, insert, pop functions
    */
}



public class Node<Value> {
    public var value: Value
    public var next: Node?

    public init(value: Value, next: Node? = nil) {
        self.value = value
        self.next = next
    }
}

var list = LinkedList<Int>()
list.append(1)
list.append(2)
list.append(3)

let node = list.head
list.head = list.head?.next

print(list.head)  // prints 2 -> 3
print(node)       // prints 1 -> 2 -> 3
```

Since `Node` is a class, I would have thought that `list.head` and `node` would both reflect updates made to either.  Why are the class semantics above behaving differently than below:

```
// Reference type example
class C { var data: Int = -1 }
var x = C()
var y = x                       // y now points to the same memory address as x
x.data = 42                     // changes the instance referred to by x (and y)
println("\(x.data), \(y.data)") // prints "42, 42"
```

Comment: Where you say "x is copied to y" - it's not. `y` simply points to the same address in memory as `x`, and that's where your object resides. So of course when you change the object, the same value (from the memory) is printed, regardless of the reference you used to access that value. That's the core of "by reference" as opposed to "by value" which is how the struct is accessed.

Comment: @khjfquantumjj I understand that but I see how the comment is confusing.  I'll update it to "y points to the same memory address as x".  I understand why the x and y example works.  I don't understand why the example I listed above doesn't behave the same as the x and y example.

Comment: A struct that contains a reference to an object (an instance of a class) only has value semantics if the object has value semantics. e.g. `Array` is a struct and contains a reference to a heap-allocated buffer (which is an instance of a class), but has logic to copy that buffer on mutations, leading to value semantics overall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you setup `LinkedList` and `Node` is class. So when a variable assign to a class variable it points to the address in memory where that class variable is stored.

From this 2 line of your code you see that

```swift
let node = list.head
list.head = list.head?.next
```

First one is `node = list.head` means that `node` is pointed to the memory address where `list.head` is stored. Means that both `node` and `list.head` at this time both assign to same memory address.

Second one is `list.head = list.head?.next` means that `list.head` is pointed to the memory address where `list.head?.next` is stored. Means that both `node` and `list.head` at this time not assign to same memory address.

So the `list.head` change memory address to `list.head?.next` doesn't affect where `node` currently memory address.

Example: A -> B -> C ( which is list memory access from a `LinkedList`)

- At first, `list.head` is pointed to memory A
- Then, `node` is pointed to memory A
- Then, `list.head` is pointed to memory B which is `list.head?.next`.
- So `node` doesn't change at all still at memory A.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, it makes so much sense now. If two objects share the same reference and the object’s value in memory changes, both will change. But if one of those objects reassigns it’s reference to a different location in memory, then they will not share the same value